# What is the $8^{th}$ term of $\left(3x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^{10}$?

Tags: calculus

What is the $8^{th}$ term of $\left(3x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^{10}$?

My solution: I'am not sure if I'am correct :)

$^{10}C_r (3x)^{10-r} \left(-\frac{y}{2}\right)^r$

where $r= 7$ since we start at $r=0$

$^{10}C_7 (3x)^3 \left(-\frac{y}{2}\right)^7$

$\left(-120\right)(27x^3)\left(\frac{y^7}{128}\right)$

$=  -\left(\frac{405}{16}\right) x^3 y^7$

Comment: Would you mind using the LaTeX editor? It improves the readability of your question.

Comment: I will try for my next questions? but any input if I"am correct

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Comment: Objection to the problem statement--Addition is commutative, so "8th term" has no meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(3x-(1/2)y)^{10}$$ general term is $$T_k=\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$$ in our case we have
$$a=3x,b=-\frac{1}{2}y,n=10,k=7$$
so
$$T_7=\binom{10}{7}(3x)^3(-\frac{1}{2}y)^7=-\frac{405}{16}x^3y^7$$

Comment: It would be nice if you did the final arithmetic.

Comment: Nice my friend Adi. :-)